# c# создать таблицу в пустом файле accdb

Tags: c#, ms-access

создал в проводнике пустой файл accdb. в программе выполняю

```
string createTableString = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name1 TEXT, name2 TEXT, name3 TEXT, birthdate TEXT, adress TEXT);";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(createTableString, oleConnection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Ошибка: Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Попробуйте изменять строку запроса на `"IF NOT EXISTS ... CREATE TABLE ..."`.

Comment: @D.Stark на месте многоточий что? IF NOT EXISTS CREATE TABLE people(id ...) так?

Comment: А это вся ошибка? Судя по [этому](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) ресурсу ошибка в `AUTOINCREMENT` и заменив на `AUTO_INCREMENT` - ошибка проходит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вся. AUTO_INCREMENT пока что не помог